# How to map nested values to flatten out a complex data structure of json - Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jackson

Having such json - "Config.json":

```
{
    "Configuration" :

      {
        "_id" :
          { "id" : 40,
            "version" : 100
          },
        "companyCode" : "AB",
        "crewType" : "STANDARD",
        "modifiedByStaffId" : "12030405",
        "lastModifiedTimestamp" : "2018-07-04T12:17:21Z",
        "offDaysAllowed" : true,
        "daysAllowed" :
          { "max" : 5,
            "min" : 1
          },
        "offDayQuota" :
          { "per" : "month",
            "value" : 20
          },
        "requestWindow" :
          { "opens" :
            {
              "value" : 1,
              "unit" : "day"
            },
            "closes" :
            {
              "value" : 2,
              "unit" : "month"
            }
          },
        "reasons" : [ "wedding", "funeral", "illness" ],
        "supportingDocuments" :
          {
            "email" : "samplemail@gmail.com",
            "canSubmit" : true
          },
        "changeReasonCode" : "TODR"
      }
  }
```

**The problem:**
I receive the json response, then I want to change his nested values and send it back, so I want to instantiate the object from this "Config.json" file and be able to easily set/change and get his nested values. For example config.setDaysAllowed_Max(4)

According to this article: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values

I tried to use the method "Mapping with Annotations" with usage of JsonProperty, so I have a Config.groovy class:

```
   class OffDayConfig {

        Object configuration
        Integer id
        Integer version
        String companyCode
        String crewType
        String modifiedByStaffId
        String lastModifiedTimestamp
        boolean offDaysAllowed
        Integer daysAllowed_Max
        Integer daysAllowed_Min
        String offDayQuota_Per
        Integer offDayQuota_Value
        Integer opensValue
        String opensUnit
        Integer closesValue
        String closesUnit
        List<String> reasons
        String supportingDocumentsEmail
        String supportingDocumentsCanSubmit
        String changeReasonCode

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @JsonProperty("configuration")
        def unpackNested(Object configuration) {
            Map<String, Integer> _id = (Map<String, Integer>) configuration._id
            this.id = _id.get("id")
            this.version = _id.get("version")

            this.companyCode = configuration.get("companyCode")
            this.crewType = configuration.get("crewType")
            this.modifiedByStaffId = configuration.get("modifiedByStaffId")
            this.lastModifiedTimestamp = configuration.get("lastModifiedTimestamp")
            this.offDaysAllowed = configuration.get("offDaysAllowed")

            Map<String, Integer> daysAllowed = (Map<String, Integer>) configuration.get("daysAllowed ")
            this.daysAllowed_Max = daysAllowed.get("daysAllowed_Max")
            this.daysAllowed_Min = daysAllowed.get("daysAllowed_Min")

            Map<String, Object> offDayQuota = (Map<String, Object>) configuration.get("offDayQuota")
            this.offDayQuota_Per = offDayQuota.get("per")
            this.offDayQuota_Value = offDayQuota.get("value")

            Map<String, Object> requestWindow = (Map<String, Object>) offDayQuota.get("requestWindow")
            Map<String, Object> opens = (Map<String, Object>) requestWindow.get("opens")
            this.opensValue = opens.get("value")
            this.opensUnit = opens.get("unit")


            Map<String, Object> closes = (Map<String, Object>) requestWindow.get("closes")
            this.closesValue = closes.get("value")
            this.closesUnit = closes.get("unit")

            this.reasons = configuration.get("reasons")

            Map<String, Object> supportingDocuments = (Map<String, Object>) configuration.get("supportingDocuments")
            this.supportingDocumentsEmail = supportingDocuments.get("email")
            this.supportingDocumentsCanSubmit = supportingDocuments.get("canSubmit")

            this.changeReasonCode = configuration.get("changeReasonCode")
        }
    }
```

Then I use an ObjectMapper to transform our source JSON, which exists as the String "json" within the test class:

```
Map offDayConfigMap = DataSource.getTestData(DataSourceType.OFF_DAY_CONFIG) //This line reads json file and creates the Map from it
String json = JsonOutput.toJson(offDayConfigMap)

OffDayConfig offDayConfig = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(OffDayConfig.class).readValue(json)
```

But the problem occurs in the method readValue(). I can't figure out why and what is the reason. Here is the log:

```
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object
        at [Source: (String)"{"Configuration":{"_id":{"id":40,"version":100},"changeReasonCode":"TODR","companyCode":"AB","crewType":"STANDARD","daysAllowed":{"max":5,"min":1},"lastModifiedTimestamp":"2018-07-04T12:17:21Z","modifiedByStaffId":"12030405","offDayQuota":{"per":"month","value":20},"offDaysAllowed":true,"reasons":["wedding","funeral","illness"],"requestWindow":{"closes":{"unit":"month","value":2},"opens":{"unit":"day","value":1}},"supportingDocuments":{"canSubmit":true,"email":"samplemail@gmail.com"}}}"; line: 1, column: 488] (through reference chain: ......................Config["Configuration"])

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:277)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:588)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:576)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:134)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:287)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1608)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1216)
        at ..................................Test.setupSpec(Test.groovy:42)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method get() on null object
        at ..................................Config.unpackNested(Config.groovy:42)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:132)
        ... 5 more
```

Dots represents the packages.

I would be grateful for help or for suggestion how to do it in another way, cause I need good way to do so, cause I will have several json files to handle in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Boaz answer I debugged my code and found 3 mistakes:

```
Map<String, Integer> daysAllowed = (Map<String, Integer>) configuration.get("daysAllowed ") -> the space after "daysAllowed " -> "daysAllowed"

Map<String, Object> requestWindow = (Map<String, Object>) offDayQuota.get("requestWindow") -> Here I should write configuration.get("requestWindow") instead of  offDayQuota.get("requestWindow"), so "offDayQuota" -> "configuration"


this.daysAllowed_Max = daysAllowed.get("daysAllowed_Max") -> "max" instead of "daysAllowed_Max"
this.daysAllowed_Min = daysAllowed.get("daysAllowed_Min") -> "min" instead of "daysAllowed_Min"
```

It works, but I don't know how to convert this flat object into the same json again.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess, the NPE is due to

```
Map<String, Integer> daysAllowed = (Map<String, Integer>) configuration.get("daysAllowed ")
this.daysAllowed_Max = daysAllowed.get("daysAllowed_Max")
this.daysAllowed_Min = daysAllowed.get("daysAllowed_Min")
```

You have a space after the "daysAllowed" string, this causes daysAllowed to be null as there is no proper key in your json file to match "daysAllowed ", and any subsequent action you take is a invoking a `get()` on a null object.

I would suggest, if not already, using a proper IDE with a debugging tool and traversing the code line by line and see what happens.

Comment: thank you for your advice. By debugging I found mistakes. Now I need to find a way to convert this flat object to same json again.

Comment: If my answer helped you please consider accepting it an upvoting.